# How to trigger clicks when you hover the a tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code , but it can't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").hover(function(){
        $(this).click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/gzCCG/

Comment: Your code would be firing the `click` event twice. Once for `mouseenter` and again for `mouseleave`. Consider just using one of those (probably `mouseenter`)

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can try `trigger()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```